# Why doesn't scheme have primitive c data types like int, float etc

Tags: scheme, primitive-types

And, how does it allocate memory from the memory pool? How many bytes for symbols, numbers and how does it handle type-casting, since it doesn't have int and float types for conversions

I really tried researching on the internet, I'm sorry i have to ask here cause I found nothing.

Comment: Please do not have the question only in the title, or it will be missed. Add it to the text also.

Comment: Typically SO questions have 1 question per post.  Also note that there are multiple implementations of scheme, and so each could use different number of bytes etc.

Comment: It's because the creator of Lisp was from a math background and didn't use limitations in a specific platform as inspiration. Scheme was originally interpreted in MacLisp and inherited the types and primitives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like other dynamically typed languages, Scheme does have types, but they're associated with *values* instead of with *variables*.  This means you can assign a boolean to a variable at one point and a number at another point in time.

Scheme doesn't use C types, because a Scheme implementation isn't necessarily tied to C at all: several compilers emit native code, without going through C. And like the other answers mention, Scheme (and Lisp before it) tries to free the programmer from having to deal with such (usually) unimportant details as the target machine's register size.

Numeric types specifically are pretty sophisticated in Lisp variants. Scheme has the so-called [numeric tower](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_sec_6.2.1) that abstracts away details of representation. Much like many "newer" languages such as Go, Python, and Ruby, Scheme will represent small integers (called "fixnums") in a machine register or word in memory.  This means it'll be fast like in C, but it will automatically switch to a different representation once the integer exceeds that size, so that arbitrary large numbers can be represented without needing any special provisioning.

The other answers have already shown you the implementation details of some Schemes.  I've recently blogged about [CHICKEN Scheme's internal data representation](http://www.more-magic.net/posts/internals-data-representation.html). The post contains links to data representation of several other Schemes, and at the end you'll find further references to data representation in Python, Ruby, Perl and older Lisp variants.

The beauty of Lisp and Scheme is that these are such old languages, but they still contain "new ideas" that only now get added to other languages. Garbage collection pretty much had to be **invented** for Lisp to work, it supported a numeric tower for a long time, object orientation was added to it at a pretty early date, anonymous procedures were in there from the beginning I think, and closures were introduced by Scheme when its authors [proved](http://repository.readscheme.org/ftp/papers/ai-lab-pubs/AIM-443.pdf) that lambda can be implemented as efficiently as `goto`.

All of this was invented between the 1950s and the 1980s. Meanwhile, it took a long long time before even garbage collection became accepted in the mainstream (basically with Java, so about 45 years), and general support for closures/anonymous procedures has become popular only in the last 5 years or so. Even tail call optimization isn't implemented in most languages; JavaScript programmers are only now discovering it. And how many "modern" languages still require the programmer to handle arbitrarily large integers using a separate set of operators and as a special type?

Note that a lot of these ideas (including the numeric type conversion you asked about) introduce additional overhead, but the overhead can be reduced by clever implementation techniques. And in the end most are a net win because they can improve programmer productivity. And if you need C or assembly performance in selected parts of your code, most implementations allow you to drop down to the metal through various tricks, so this is not closed off to you. The disadvantage would be that it isn't standardized (though there *is* [cffi](https://common-lisp.net/project/cffi/) for Common Lisp), but like I said, Scheme isn't tied to C so it would be very rude if the spec enforced a C foreign function interface onto non-C implementations.

Comment: Can you explain further how Scheme automatically switches to a different representation?

Comment: The primitive operations on numeric types are built to detect integer overflow if passed two fixnums, and they will switch to a bignum type when that happens. This depends on the exact operation and implementation.  Sometimes it's easier to simply convert the fixnums to bignums, perform the operation and then attempt to reduce back to a fixnum if it fits.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question is implementation dependent.

Here is how it was done in the Scheme compiler workshop.
The compiler generated machine code for a 32-bit Sparc machine.

See http://www.cs.indiana.edu/eip/compile/back.html

```
Data Formats

All of our data are represented by 32-bit words, with the lower three bits as a kind of type-tag. While this would normally only allow us eight types, we cheat a little bit: Booleans, empty-lists and characters can be represented in (much) less than 32 bits, so we steal a few of their data bits for an ``extended'' type tag.

Numbers:                                                                 
--------------------------------------                                   
| 29-bit 2's complement integer  000 |                                   
--------------------------------------                                   

Booleans:                                                                
      -------------------       -------------------                        
  #t: | ... 1 00000 001 |   #f: | ... 0 00000 001 |                        
      -------------------       -------------------                        

Empty lists:
-----------------                                                         
| ... 00001 001 |                                                         
-----------------                                                         

Characters:                                                              
---------------------------------------                                   
| ... 8-bit character data  00010 001 |                                   
---------------------------------------                                   
Pairs, strings, symbols, vectors and closures maintain a 3-bit type tag, but devote the rest of their 32 bits to an address into the heap where the actual value is stored:

Pairs:                                                                   
---------------       -------------                                      
| address 010 |   --> | car | cdr |                                      
-----\---------  /    -------------                                      
      -----------                                                        

Strings:                                                                 
---------------       -------------------------------------------------  
| address 011 |   --> | length | string data (may span many words)... |  
-----\---------  /    -------------------------------------------------  
      -----------                                                        

Symbols:                                                                 
---------------       --------------------------                         
| address 100 |   --> | symbol name (a string) |                         
-----\---------  /    --------------------------                         
      -----------                                                        

Vectors:                                                                 
---------------                                                          
| address 101 |                                                          
-----|---------                                                          
     v                                                                   
  -----------------------------------------------------------            
  | length | (v-ref 0) | (v-ref 1) | ... | (v-ref length-1) |            
  -----------------------------------------------------------            

Closures:                                                                
---------------                                                          
| address 110 |                                                          
-----|---------                                                          
     v                                                                   
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  | length | code pointer | (free 0) | (free 1) | ... | (free length-1) |
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that it has primitive data types, but you as a programmer don't need to worry about it.

The designer of Lisp was from a math background and didn't use limitations in a specific platform as inspiration. In math a number isn't 32 bits but we do differentiate between exact numbers an inexact ones.

Scheme was originally interpreted in MacLisp and inherited the types and primitives of MacLisp. MacLisp is based on Lisp 1.5.

A variable doesn't have a type and most implementations have a machine pointer as it's data type. Primitives like chars, symbols and small integers are stored right in the address by manipulating the last significant bits as a type flag, which would always be zero for an actual object since the machine aligns objects in memory to register width.

If you add two integers that becomes bigger than the size of the result is of a different type. In C it would overflow.

```
;; This is Common Lisp, but the same happens in Scheme
(type-of 1)  ; ==> BIT
(type-of 10) ; ==> (INTEGER 0 281474976710655)
(type-of 10000000000000000) ; ==> (INTEGER (281474976710655))
```

The type of the objects are different even though we treat them the same. The first two doesn't use any extra space than the pointer but the last is a pointer to an actual object that is allocated on the heap.

All of this is implementation dependent. The Scheme standard does not dictate how its done, but many does it just like this. You [can read the standard](http://www.r6rs.org/) and it says nothing about how to model numbers, only the behavior. You may make a R6RS Scheme that stores everything in byte arrays.